# org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect

Tags: java, swing, hibernate

I am trying to fix an issue but I couldnt do this. I created a JFrame to input some database information (IP, Name, User, Password).

After this, I removed the hibernate cfg file, and in HibernatUtil class I inserted the configs by myself using .setProperty. I am using the same configs of the cfg file that I removed, which was working but now using setProperty it isnt.

Netbeans is showing an Hibernate error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
```

And a SQL Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The syntax of the connection URL 'jdbc:jtds:sybase//ip/nomeDoBanco' is invalid
```

**UPDATE**

My HibernateUtil class:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect");
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver");
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url);
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username);
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Node.class);
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Fault.class);
        factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

I am using these jars:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your driver does not seem to be right..

Refer this...

```
#hibernate.dialect org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect
#hibernate.connection.driver_class com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver
#hibernate.connection.username sa
#hibernate.connection.password sasasa
#hibernate.connection.url jdbc:sybase:Tds:co3061835-a:5000/tempdb
```

you should be using the SybDriver..

Change your url to

```
jdbc:sybase:Tds:ip:5000/nomeDoBanco
```

Comment: I will try this, but just one comment, is jdbc:sybase:Tds or jdbc:sybase:jtds ?

Comment: I think your url should be fine.. Just try to change the driver name

Comment: Nikhil, I changed the dialect and the driver_class, take a look at the update please.

Comment: ok see this link , http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~poggi/didattica/progettoas09/esercitazioni/esercitazione4/hibernate.properties

Comment: I just add jconn4.jar

Comment: This should be your url jdbc:sybase:Tds:localhost:5000/dbtest use tds

Comment: You solved the problem Nikhil, thanks a lot. I changed the url to dbc:sybase:Tds:localhost:5000/dbtest, as you said !

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this line is correct ?

```
cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

It seems to me that you are setting a driver class not known by your environnement.